# Adobe AIR application integrity

Tags: air

Is there any way to check the integrity of the application just before the application starts up? (to prevent anyone changing the application after it is installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe AIR automatically does this when you sign your code and package your aar file.  If you touch anything inside it aar file after signing it, you should get an error.  See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/air_security/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11c0f598475-7ffa.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Adobe AIR itself provides any such integrity checker.

A (non-optimal) solution would be to have a database of md5 hashes of all or select important files, and verify it again at start-up. (you could use [this](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/scripts.html) for the md5 hashing.)